# Ranorex. iframe access issue

Tags: iframe, webdriver, ranorex

I try to use WebDriver endpoint with Ranorex and all works well when Ranorex works with a simple path, but not when it works with iframe.

It will be better if I provide the example:

```
<div id="layout">
    <span id="element1"></span>
    <iframe id="frame1">
        #document
            <html>
                <span id="element2"></span>
            </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

- Ranorex endpoint using:

1. I can access to any element Ranorex endpoint using:

   ```
   //span[#'element1']

   //iframe[#'frame1']//span[#'element2']
   ```

- WebDriver endpoint using:

2. I can access the elements that contained outside the iframe: (including the iframe itself)

   ```
   //span[#'element1']

   //iframe[#'frame1']
   ```
3. I have the error when I try to get access with WebDriver endpoint to any element that contains inside iframe :

   ```
   //iframe[#'frame1']//span[#'element2']
   ```

How I can use elements in iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

As in the Selenium we need to switch between frames.
I found that WebDriverDocument has the ability to switch frames:

```
WebDriverDocument wd = WebDriverDocument.FromPatch("//*[1]");
wd.SwitchToFrame("//iframe[@id='frame1']", "xpath");
// wd.SwitchToFrame("frane1", "id"); - also availabled
```

After that I can manage elements that contained inner iframe:

```
WebElement  wl  = "//span[#'element2']";
```